# An urn contains n unique marbles. I draw k of them with replacement, and get r duplicates (r>0). What is the MLE for n?

Tags: probability

What is the MLE for n which is the total number of marbles in the urn? 
What is the expected value of n? 
And what if r = 0 (no duplicates were drawn)? Can anything be said about n?

A duplicate means that that marble was seen before at least once. The r duplicates could all be the same marble or they could be different ones. It doesn't matter.

The r=0 case seems paradoxical to me because one would think that if n2 > n1, then P(r=0 | n2, k)>P(r=0 | n1, k). The more marbles in the urn the more likely you are to not get any duplicates after k draws. However, this means that the pmf defined by f(n) = P(r=0 | n, k) (as a function of n basically) cannot exist because it could never add up to 1. No matter how you assign the probabilities, it seems that since n ranges from let's say 1 to inf, and f(n) is monotonically increasing, it cannot be a pmf.

Motivation for question:

I was working on a machine learning problem where the solution space was so vast, that I could only sample from the solution space. Enumerating all the possible solutions and trying them one by one would have been too impractical. I noticed that after generating 1500 "candidate solutions", I did not get any duplicates (though my code was not checking for duplicates), so I wondered if there was anything I could say about the size of the solution space based on this. This led me to the statement of the abstract problem above. Generating a "candidate solution" is analogous to drawing from an urn.

Comment: Do you want the MLE for $n$ as your question title says or the "expected value" (which assumes that $n$ is a random variable?) as the text of the question says?$

Comment: How is drawing a specific marble for the third time treated (a 'triplicate')? Is it just one more "duplicate"? Or are you saying that no marble was drawn more than twice?

Comment: I added clarification. This is definitely not a homework question, it's a question I made up. Not sure how they decided it was a homework question.

Comment: @BasilBeirouti on this website many questions appear that are text book questions. Such questions are often  elementary, abstract and/or simple. You question looks like one of those (and it probably does appear in some textbooks even when you may have come across the question differently). It is for this reason that someone has flagged the question. It is not done because the question is not allowed, but because we do not want to turn into a straightforward do-my-homework-cheating-machinery-that-is-giving-me-complete-answers-without-me-learning-anything.

Comment: To resolve this problem you should indicate more precisely the issue that you have with this problem. What have you already tried and at which step(s) do you get stuck. By giving more information about your problem you will learn more yourself, but also potential future visitors that have the same problem and are looking for an answer.

Comment: Also, more related to the question, what are you using this for? A full exact answer (like a formula) will be complex (it will be a sum of many terms that I guess may not be simplified). So getting an answer by using simulations might be a better strategy. But this depends on what the motivation is for this question. Do you want to learn about probabilities, learn about methods to solve urn problems, or do you want to learn to compute simulations?

Comment: An exact solution might have a simpler solution after all (solving for getting k-r unique marbles out of k draws is a simpler problem but equivalent).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Martijn. I came up with this problem because I was working on a machine learning problem where the solution space was so vast, that I could only sample from the solution space. Enumerating all the possible solutions and trying them one by one would have been too impractical. I noticed that after generating 1500 "candidate solutions", I did not get any duplicates (though my code was not checking for duplicates), so I wondered if there was anything I could say about the size of the solution space based on this. This led me to the statement of the abstract problem above.

Comment: What I would like is insight more than anything. It is no longer a practical question, more of a philosophical one.

Comment: The r=0 case seems paradoxical to me because one would think that if n2 > n1, then P(r=0 | n2, k)>P(r=0 | n1, k). The more marbles in the urn the more likely you are to not get any duplicates after k draws. However, this means that the pmf defined by f(n) = P(r=0 | n, k)  (as a function of n basically) cannot exist because it could never add up to 1. No matter how you assign the probabilities, it seems that since n ranges from let's say 1 to inf, and f(n) is monotonically increasing, it cannot be a pmf.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90944/discussion-between-basil-beirouti-and-martijn-weterings).